# How do I lay out a wxpython widgets in a loop,?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I am trying to pull rows of data from an sqlite database and display them in gui using the wxpython module. From the little I understand we use the GridSizer and BoxSizer to organise and place our widgets in the GUI. So I have been trying to organise this GUI that have  three container(BoxSizers) stacked on top each other. Each of the container hold some widgets. Now the issue is the last container(BoxSizer) contain the widgets that will be housing the values from the rows of data gotten from the database. The widgets are appearing at the top of the above the widgets in the first BoxSizer, instead of appearing as the last BoxSizer the ay I meant to do it. Also it only show the first row gotten from the database instead of all.
This is how I added the `BoxSizers`

```
self.main_sizer.Add(self.pay_fee_heading_box_sizer, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
self.main_sizer.Add(pay_fees_grid_container_sizer, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
self.main_sizer.Add(self.search_result_box_sizer, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
```

And this where I added the widgets to the `BoxSizer` that is bordering me.

```
self.search_result_box_sizer.AddMany(
                    [

                    (wx.StaticText(self, label=student_name + str(" ")), 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5),
                    (wx.StaticText(self, label=student_class + str(" ")), 1, wx.ALL| wx.EXPAND, 5),
                    (wx.StaticText(self, label=str(amount_paid) + str(" ")), 1, wx.ALL| wx.EXPAND, 5),
                    
                    ])
```

Your help has help me a lot in coming this far and I know it well help me cross this obstacle too. Thanking you in anticipation of your help.

Comment: better show `minal working code` with some example data - so we could simply copy and test it.

Comment: you could also put screenshot with current windows and information what is wrong and what you need.

Comment: I'm trying to make the given example work as a working program, and somehow I'm not succeeding. I can't imagine what the problem is. Without a working sample, no one will probably answer your question.